# Recursion in sort function

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, recursion

I have a huge compare function which I'm using to sort a 2D array with both number and string values, and I want to make it smaller. I've have used same blocks of code repeatedly inside each other, and I think that's redundant. I think I can make the code smaller using recursion but I don't think I've done that before, and my sort function seems really complex. It's as follows:

```
check if a & b is array
check if a & b is number or string
    if number
        check if a equals to b
            repeat same process with different index
    if string
        check if a equals to b
            repeat same process with different index
```

An example array:

```
var artists = [
    ["Katy Perry",          "3",    "9"     ],
    ["Enrique Iglesias",    "3",    "9"     ],
    ["Taylor Swift",        "2",    "9"     ],
    ["Evanescence",         "4",    "10"    ],
    ["Bruno Mars",          "1",    "5"     ],
    ["Shania Twain",        "3",    "12"    ],
    ["Amanda Abizaid",      "2",    "2"     ],
    ["Death Cab For Cutie", "2",    "2"     ],
    ["Simple Plan",         "1",    "2"     ],
];

// sort and prioritize columns by 2, 1, 0, sort order for each 1 = asc
artists.sort(compare.bind([2, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]));
```

Same array after sort:

```
var artists = [
    ["Simple Plan",         "1",    "2"     ],
    ["Amanda Abizaid",      "2",    "2"     ],
    ["Death Cab For Cutie", "2",    "2"     ],
    ["Bruno Mars",          "1",    "5"     ],
    ["Taylor Swift",        "2",    "9"     ],
    ["Enrique Iglesias",    "3",    "9"     ],
    ["Katy Perry",          "3",    "9"     ],
    ["Evanescence",         "4",    "10"    ],
    ["Shania Twain",        "3",    "12"    ],
];
```

Actual compare function:

```
// compare is passed to Array.prototype.sort
// array2bSorted.sort(sortable.compare.bind([cols, orders]));

compare : function(a, b) {

    var columns = sortable.explodeInnerArrays(this[0]);
    var orders  = sortable.explodeInnerArrays(this[1]);

    var primaryA = a[columns[0]];
    var primaryB = b[columns[0]];

    if (primaryA instanceof Array) {
        primaryA = a[columns[0]][0];
    }
    if (primaryB instanceof Array) {
        primaryB = b[columns[0]][0];
    }

    switch (sortable.checkDataType(primaryA)) {
        case "number":
            if (primaryA == primaryB && columns.length > 1) {

                var secondaryA = a[columns[1]];
                var secondaryB = b[columns[1]];

                if (secondaryA instanceof Array) {
                    secondaryA = a[columns[1]][0];
                }
                if (secondaryB instanceof Array) {
                    secondaryB = b[columns[1]][0];
                }

                switch (sortable.checkDataType(secondaryA)) {
                    case "number":
                        if (secondaryA == secondaryB && columns.length > 2) {

                            var tertiaryA = a[columns[2]];
                            var tertiaryB = b[columns[2]];

                            if (tertiaryA instanceof Array) {
                                tertiaryA = a[columns[2]][0];
                            }
                            if (tertiaryB instanceof Array) {
                                tertiaryB = b[columns[2]][0];
                            }

                            switch (sortable.checkDataType(tertiaryA)) {
                                case "number":
                                    return (tertiaryA - tertiaryB) * orders[2];
                                    break;
                                case "string":
                                    tertiaryA = sortable.removePunctuation(tertiaryA);
                                    tertiaryB = sortable.removePunctuation(tertiaryB);
                                    if (tertiaryA < tertiaryB) {
                                        return -1 * orders[2];
                                    }
                                    if (tertiaryA > tertiaryB) {
                                        return 1 * orders[2];
                                    }
                                    return 0;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        return (secondaryA - secondaryB) * orders[1];
                        break;
                    case "string":
                        if (secondaryA == secondaryB && columns.length > 2) {

                            var tertiaryA = a[columns[2]];
                            var tertiaryB = b[columns[2]];

                            if (tertiaryA instanceof Array) {
                                tertiaryA = a[columns[2]][0];
                            }
                            if (tertiaryB instanceof Array) {
                                tertiaryB = b[columns[2]][0];
                            }

                            switch (sortable.checkDataType(tertiaryA)) {
                                case "number":
                                    return (tertiaryA - tertiaryB) * orders[2];
                                    break;
                                case "string":
                                    tertiaryA = sortable.removePunctuation(tertiaryA);
                                    tertiaryB = sortable.removePunctuation(tertiaryB);
                                    if (tertiaryA < tertiaryB) {
                                        return -1 * orders[2];
                                    }
                                    if (tertiaryA > tertiaryB) {
                                        return 1 * orders[2];
                                    }
                                    return 0;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        secondaryA = sortable.removePunctuation(secondaryA);
                        secondaryB = sortable.removePunctuation(secondaryB);
                        if (secondaryA < secondaryB) {
                            return -1 * orders[1];
                        }
                        if (secondaryA > secondaryB) {
                            return 1 * orders[1];
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
            return (primaryA - primaryB) * orders[0];
            break;
        case "string":
            if (primaryA == primaryB && columns.length > 1) {

                var secondaryA = a[columns[1]];
                var secondaryB = b[columns[1]];

                if (secondaryA instanceof Array) {
                    secondaryA = a[columns[1]][0];
                }
                if (secondaryB instanceof Array) {
                    secondaryB = b[columns[1]][0];
                }

                switch (sortable.checkDataType(secondaryA)) {
                    case "number":
                        if (secondaryA == secondaryB) {

                            var tertiaryA = a[columns[2]];
                            var tertiaryB = b[columns[2]];

                            if (tertiaryA instanceof Array) {
                                tertiaryA = a[columns[2]][0];
                            }
                            if (tertiaryB instanceof Array) {
                                tertiaryB = b[columns[2]][0];
                            }

                            switch (sortable.checkDataType(tertiaryA)) {
                                case "number":
                                    return (tertiaryA - tertiaryB) * orders[2];
                                    break;
                                case "string":
                                    tertiaryA = sortable.removePunctuation(tertiaryA);
                                    tertiaryB = sortable.removePunctuation(tertiaryB);
                                    if (tertiaryA < tertiaryB) {
                                        return -1 * orders[2];
                                    }
                                    if (tertiaryA > tertiaryB) {
                                        return 1 * orders[2];
                                    }
                                    return 0;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        return (secondaryA - secondaryB) * orders[1];
                        break;
                    case "string":
                        if (secondaryA == secondaryB && columns.length > 2) {

                            var tertiaryA = a[columns[2]];
                            var tertiaryB = b[columns[2]];

                            if (tertiaryA instanceof Array) {
                                tertiaryA = a[columns[2]][0];
                            }
                            if (tertiaryB instanceof Array) {
                                tertiaryB = b[columns[2]][0];
                            }

                            switch (sortable.checkDataType(tertiaryA)) {
                                case "number":
                                    return (tertiaryA - tertiaryB) * order;
                                    break;
                                case "string":
                                    tertiaryA = sortable.removePunctuation(tertiaryA);
                                    tertiaryB = sortable.removePunctuation(tertiaryB);
                                    if (tertiaryA < tertiaryB) {
                                        return -1 * orders[2];
                                    }
                                    if (tertiaryA > tertiaryB) {
                                        return 1 * orders[2];
                                    }
                                    return 0;
                                    break;
                            }
                        }
                        secondaryA = sortable.removePunctuation(secondaryA);
                        secondaryB = sortable.removePunctuation(secondaryB);
                        if (secondaryA < secondaryB) {
                            return -1 * orders[1];
                        }
                        if (secondaryA > secondaryB) {
                            return 1 * orders[1];
                        }
                        break;
                }

            }
            primaryA = sortable.removePunctuation(primaryA);
            primaryB = sortable.removePunctuation(primaryB);
            if (primaryA < primaryB) {
                return -1 * orders[0];
            }
            if (primaryA > primaryB) {
                return 1 * orders[0];
            }
            break;
    }
},
```

Compare function sorts the array by multiple columns each with their own sort order. And since columns are passed in an array, initial indexes have higher priority.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6ckner3j/)

Using recursion I've come up with the following code, but it doesn't work. Array is not sorted. It doesn't throw any error either. <sub>(I removed some unrelated parts to make it look simpler)</sub>

```
compare : function(a, b) {

    var columns = sortable.explodeInnerArrays(this[0]);
    var orders  = sortable.explodeInnerArrays(this[1]);

    function loop(a, b, index) {

        var currentA = a[columns[index]];
        var currentB = b[columns[index]];

        switch (sortable.checkDataType(currentA)) {
            case "number":
                if (currentA == currentB) {
                    loop(a, b, (index+1));
                }
                return (currentA - currentB) * orders[index];
                break;
            case "string":
                if (currentA == currentB) {
                    loop(a, b, (index+1));
                }
                if (currentA < currentB) {
                    return -1 * orders[index];
                }
                if (currentA > currentB) {
                    return 1 * orders[index];
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    loop(a,b,0);
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Yes, definitively. Either recursion or a loop. You'll need this anyway to support more than 3 columns. Have you tried it?

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, still working on it. Trying recursion. I don't know how I would go with a loop.

Comment: If this is not just for educational purposes, why don't you just use the Array.prototype.sort() method? This is supported from IE >= 5.5, and of course in all modern web browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: @JacobHeater I'm sorting a 2D array both with number and string values, so I need to pass a custom function to sort method.

Comment: @akinuri, I see. I'll reevaluate now that I understand the use case.

Comment: Could you make an example of an input and expected output? Not sure if what you show in jsfiddle is working well or not

Comment: @juvian Fiddle is working fine. `sortable.sort(artists, [2, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]);` First argument is the array to be sorted, second array are the columns (sorted by their priority), and the third array is sort order for the columns (1 for asc, -1 for des).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem, and create my first recursion.

Simply calling `loop` function inside `compare` doesn't do anything because it returns `1` or `-1` to `compare` function and `compare` function doesn't return anything. I needed to return the value that the `loop` function returns. `return loop(a, b, index)` did the trick.

```
compare : function(a, b) {

    var columns = sortable.explodeInnerArrays(this[0]);
    var orders  = sortable.explodeInnerArrays(this[1]);

    function loop(a, b, index) {

        var currentA = a[columns[index]];
        var currentB = b[columns[index]];

        if (currentA instanceof Array) {
            currentA = a[columns[index]][0];
        }
        if (currentB instanceof Array) {
            currentB = b[columns[index]][0];
        }

        switch (sortable.checkDataType(currentA)) {
            case "number":
                if (currentA == currentB) {
                    return loop(a, b, (index+1));
                }
                return (currentA - currentB) * orders[index];
                break;
            case "string":
                if (currentA == currentB) {
                    return loop(a, b, (index+1));
                }
                currentA = sortable.removePunctuation(currentA);
                currentB = sortable.removePunctuation(currentB)
                if (currentA < currentB) {
                    return -1 * orders[index];
                }
                if (currentA > currentB) {
                    return 1 * orders[index];
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    return loop(a, b, 0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> I've have used same blocks of code inside if and switch statements more than once and I think it's redundant.

Before trying to jump into recursion, first try refactoring: first use [Extract Method](http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) to move the duplicate code to its own function.